# How to include setup.py absolute path in PKG-INFO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am trying to add my project location as part of PKG-INFO. I wanted that information to create some other relative paths which contains some resource files. I could keep those folder as `package_data` or `data_files`, But every time i  modify files  i need to do `python setup.py install` as well. So if I could add setup.py abosolute path as part of metadata, I could parse that and form path to my required folders.

```
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   name='myproject',
   packages=find_packages(),
   long_description=os.path.dirname(__file__)
)
```

This is part of my setup.py. But while installing above setup.py by `python setup.py install` in the PKG-INFO file `description=UNKNOWN` is coming. How to add this ?

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to add data/non-python files to the sdist/wheel, or do you want to add a description?

Comment: I want to add location(full path in file system) of setup.py to the summary of PKG-INFO.  I want this information in my project later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the long_description to `os.path.realpath` instead of `os.path.dirname(__file__)` and it worked!

```
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   name='myproject',
   packages=find_packages(),
   long_description=os.path.realpath(__file__)
)
```

What could be the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Setuptools has a `description` and a `long_description` field, you are missing the former:

```
setup(
   name='myproject',
   packages=find_packages(),
   description='a project that does X',
   long_description=os.path.dirname(__file__)
)
```

Comment: Thanks Nils, I tried that too. But still same result.